# Prevent VSCode from asking for GitHub credentials when typing Golang imports?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

Every time I attempt to import a Golang library from a Github repo, VSCode asks me for my Github credentials.

[image: OpenSSH Prompt for Github credentials]

This happens on literally every keystroke, so I can't really even type an import path without mashing the escape key while I type. Is there a way to disable this, somehow? I entered a Personal Access Token at one of the prompts, but this didn't stop it from re-appearing.

Here are the Go extension entries from `settings.json`. Everything else is the default.

```
{
    "go.useLanguageServer": true,
    "go.autocompleteUnimportedPackages": true,
}
```

Comment: go to vs code extension you are using and disable the imports tool

Comment: What's the setting for that? I'm just using the "Go" extension, and intellisense on "go.import" doesn't give me anything that looks like it applies.

Comment: can you add your extension settings it is stored in json

Comment: Added to the question.

Comment: did you try setting autocompleteUnimportedPackages to false

Comment: Yes, to no avail.

Comment: "go.formatTool" : "gofmt" I think by default it is goimports which auto fixes imports

Comment: This didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the Golang module in a private GitHub repository?

If so then you've got to update your `.gitconfig` with your credentials.
You can do that with,

```
git config --global url."https://${username}:${personal_access_token}@github.com".insteadOf "https://github.com"
```

Make sure to url-encode your token/username.